# UWP: are there other ItemsPanelTemplate(s) besides ItemsWrapGrid

Tags: templates, gridview, uwp

All of my `GridView` searches are turning up examples only showing `ItemsWrapGrid`, to use as the `ItemsPanelTemplate` in a `GridView`. Are there any other predefined templates ?

Answer (score 0):

Well, you could put a [Panel](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.ui.xaml.controls.panel?view=winrt-19041) -derived class as the ItemsPanelTemplate.For example, you could use Grid, ItemsStackPanel, StackPanel, RelativePanel, ItemsWrapGrid and etc.

Comment: I guess I don't understand, well enough, how Panel is used. I did notice that ItemsPanelTemplate is derived from that but I don't know if you can use other Panel-derived classes in GridView. Will any of them work ? How do I determine the behaviors ?

Comment: Please bear with me, I've only been experimenting with UWP for a few weeks and I'm stumbling through the documentation, trying to absorb it.

Comment: The panel derived class is used to position and arrange child objects in a UI page. The default value for GridView's  ItemsPanelTemplate is ItemsWrapGrid. You could use other panels like ItemsStackPanel instead.

Comment: Thanks, Roy. I did find more info to read. If I understand, using ItemsWrapGrid will give it the view "virtualization" which is needed for large datasets. What I don't understand is the visual differences of using oine type of panel versus another. The documentation is just too vague as to what the panel does versus the GridView itself. I guess I'll have to experiment sometime.

Comment: Here is the document about the virtualization and panel: [UI virtualization](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/debug-test-perf/optimize-gridview-and-listview#ui-virtualization)